# Data source for determining postal codes given location?

Tags: data, address, postal-code

What is the best data source for determining international postal codes given a latitude & longitude?

Comment: SCW  are you looking for a paid or free source for global postcodes?

Comment: A preference for free, but both are fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paid for

**EZ-Locate** (TeleAtlas - owned by TomTom)

http://www.geocode.com/index.cfm?module=download

**NAVmart** (NavTeq owned by Nokia)

http://www.navmart.com/geocoding.php

http://www.navmart.com/geocoding_services.php

Free

**Via Michelin** (API and better coverage in Europe rather than globally)

http://dev.viamichelin.com/

**Geonames** (good open-source - patchy accuracy in rural locations)

http://www.geonames.org/export/reverse-geocoding.html

Answer (score 1):

Here another one: (10,000 calls per day free)
https://simplegeo.com/docs/clients-code-libraries

Answer (score 1):

I asked a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8191/advice-on-geocoding-ip-addresses) recently, trying to achieve the opposite (had city, country wanted lat/long). I used this free [database](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php). It won't give you postcodes (so it's not really an answer), but it does give you city and country, if that is useful.