# Batch convert ipaddress to coordinates

Tags: convert, batch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Advice on geocoding IP addresses](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8191/advice-on-geocoding-ip-addresses)

I am wondering if there are any applications that will batch convert ipaddress to geographic coordinates? Some background on the project. My friend wants to know where fans of hockey teams live throughout the US/Canada/World. He made a simple online survey and apparently it captures each person's ipaddress. All we want to do is translate the ipaddress into a semi-accurate geo-location and tie that data point to a team.

The part I'm not familiar with is converting the ipaddress to coordinates. We don't need that much accuracy, within 2-3 miles is plenty accurate for this for-fun project. I have found a few applications that will convert ipaddress to coordinates, but they're all manually intensive. So far the survey has 2000+ replies, so that's a lot of manual data entry. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

HostIP might a possibility - it has a pretty easy-to-use [API](http://www.hostip.info/use.html).