# Downloadable, Open Source, IP GeoLocation database

Tags: data, open-source-gis, geolocation

I have an open source project. I need a similarly open source IP GeoLocation database i.e. IP address to country (and ideally city). Ideally with a license that allows redistribution.

This is a question that's been asked before ([Advice on geocoding IP addresses](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8191/advice-on-geocoding-ip-addresses/21116#21116), and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232516/geocode-an-ip-address most noteably), but they were for RESTful/API interfaces; I want a database that can be downloaded and used offline.

So far I've found two potentials:

[IP2Location's 'Lite'](http://ip2location.com/) - which claims to be open source but doesn't allow redistribution and has a very restrictive set of terms of use.

[MaxMind's GeoLite2](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) - Released under a Attribution ShareAlike Unported License, but again with restrictions on redistribution.

Does anyone know of any suitable datasets?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a database I wrote for IP to country that is open source under Apache2:
https://github.com/geoacumen/geoacumen-country

If anyone has any insight on how one would build an IP to City mapping database I would also be very interested.

Comment: ASN doesn't mean geolocation, but it is better than nothing, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you try this one
https://ipinfodb.com/free-database

You can try this one as well: https://db-ip.com/db/.

Now, remember, they are there for your money, so the free db is lite version of what their commercial products is.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a bit late, but will add it anyways for any future visitor of this post.

I developed a Database with every IPv4 / IPv6 with over 21 properties per IP range. The project can be found here: [ip.js0.ch](https://ip.js0.ch/)

Visit the website if you are interested, still need feedback / suggestions for improvement :)

Comment: This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in ip.js0.ch.
If spelling is correct, try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN